# Use of a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, lightbox

I am using a lightbox script, [Clearbox](http://www.clearbox.hu/index_en.html). For various reasons ( main one is I can't use a link to open the lightboxin this particular setup), I need to set up a function as follows to open an image in the lightbox:

```
function initCBox(){
var img1 = $(select.currentImg).attr('src');
var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt')    

CB_Open('href=img1,,title=label');  

}
```

Clearbox wants the href to be an actual link but I need it to be the img1 var. I'm a newbie with this so any help or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You could construct the string like this: `CB_Open('href='+img1',,title='+label+'');`

Comment: @AttilaOláh forgot a `+` there :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CB_Open('href='+img1+',,title='+label);
```

you need to concatenate it in

Comment: Another question. I want to include text in a div, class='caption' but not include a ul class='icon' that is within that div. My code:
`function initCBox(){

 var img1 = $(select.currentImg).attr('src');

var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt');

var desc = $('.item.active .caption').not('ul.icon').text();
 
CB_Open('href=' + img1 + ',,title=' + label + ',,comment=' + desc +'');
  
 
}
`
my var desc is not working, since I get the text in the ul.

Comment: @Mike hm... I would suggest making another question for it on SO with the html markup.  I can't see anything obviously wrong with it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You could use string concatenation to build that parameter string before you pass it to CB_Open:

```
function initCBox(){
    var img1 = $(select.currentImg).attr('src');
    var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt')    

    CB_Open('href=' + img1 + ',,title=' + label);  
}
```

Alternatively, you can see if CB_Open can take an "options hash" object - this is cleaner, if it's supported:

```
function initCBox(){
    var img1 = $(select.currentImg).attr('src');
    var label = $(select.currentImg).attr('alt')    

    CB_Open({
        href: img1,
        title: label
    });  
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
CB_Open('href=' + img1 + ',,title=label');
```